# Is there a way to copy the data from a constructor and use another constructor to add another data

Tags: java, linked-list

I ran into some problem and I really need your wisdom on this. So I have a created a LinkedList class like this:

```
public class LinkedList{
    public class Node{
    public Object uid;
    public int size;
    public Object job;
    public Node next;

    Node(){
    }

    Node(Object newUID,Object newJob){
        uid = newUID;
        job = newJob;
        next = null;
    }

    Node(Object newUID, Object newJob, Node nextNode){
        uid = newUID;
        job = newJob;
        next = nextNode;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is a part of the code of my main class that I got stuck:

```
 Node Last = new Node(new Integer(10),new Integer(100));
 Node Prev = new Node(Last's uid(10), Last's Job(100), Last)
```

The last line is where I got stuck. I need a way to copy the data of node `Last` and add the next `Node` so that it could become the previous `Node` of `Last`

Thank you

Comment: Please don't write long comments in your StackOverflow code blocks. Put them outside the code.

Comment: This isn't entirely clear.  Why can't you do `new Node(last.uid, last.job, last)`?

Comment: Oh man, thank you Oliver! I'm such an idiot